# Ignore firefox SSL security warning with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl, warnings

When a form submits in ssl in firefox, to a none secure page, this warning shows:

> Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an >unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.

I need a solution to ignore this message. I think with jquery and this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#some-id').trigger('click'); 
});
```

Now I need an identifier or keyword to point the continue bottom of warning to automatically press it with above code. Can anybody help me or give me a better solution with javascript or jquery to resolve this problem?

Comment: This shouldn't be allowed because of the security risk to the user. Imagine they are on their banking website, they would definitely want to know if information is being sent to a non-secured site. This behaviour is by-design and can't be bypassed

Comment: there is no security risk and I need to hide this warning

Comment: Perhaps there is no security risk in **this** instance, but if there was a way around this, there would be risks in all other cases. If the notification is bothering your users, make sure that the form is secured with the same certificate. What's the point of your certificate if you're not using it to secure your data?

Comment: User insert it's data in my form and submit them, then my application process them and post resul (that aren't secure) to callback url

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this and even if you could, you **shouldn't**. You cannot access browser dialogs using client-side script and that warning is there for a reason, to inform the user of what exactly is happening behind the scenes.

Being able to do this would present a massive security risk.

Comment: this warning just is in FF and any other browser shows it. There is no security issue here and this warning bother the users.

Comment: Being able to dismiss this using Javascript *would* be a security issue because I wouldn't realize my data is being passed from a secure domain to an insecure one. Being able to communicate with browser dialogs of any sort of this way would be another huge security loophole

Comment: No user data will be sent to none secure page. Posted data are generated in my application and there is no security issue for sending them

Comment: Posted data *is* user data. I know you think it's not an issue in your case, but Firefox doesn't know what you personally are doing, it just has to assume the notification is required. What you're trying to achieve is impossible.